# {PHP} Поиск значения меньше чем n, в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Задача следующая: необходимо найти все значения меньше среднего, находящиеся в массиве и вывести их номера и значения. Только начинаю познавать программирование, это мой первый вопрос на stackoverflow, так что палками прошу не бить.

```
    <?php
    $num_array = 25;
    $arr = (range(0,25));      
    $arr = array_fill(0, 25, '');
        for ($i=0; $i < $num_array; $i++) { 
            $arr[$i] = rand(0,1000);
        }
        
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r ($arr);
    echo '<pre>';
    $summ=array_sum($arr); //В массиве содержится информация о товаре, нам нужно найти товары цена которых ниже средней.
    $sr_st=$summ/$num_array; //Считаем средюю цену товара
    echo $sr_st;
?>
```

Comment: Суть вопроса не ясна.

Comment: Пройдите ещё одним циклом, сравнивая значения с $sr_st с помощью if

Comment: @MBo, мужик, спасибо...